# Using Object.keys with a while loop to find object keys within an input string

Tags: javascript, loops, key, javascript-objects

I have code that's meant to take an input string, find the name of an operation (add, subtract, multiply, or divide) and do the indicated operation on the numbers also included in the input string. So if my input looks like this

```
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d  subtract
```

I want my program to find the word "subtract" and then subtract 2 from 1, 3 from the result and then 4 from the result of that. So far, I have my operations defined as global variables at the top of my program like this:

```
var operations = {      
  add: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return Number(a) + Number(b);
  },
  subtract: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a - b;
  },
  multiply: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a * b;
  },
  divide: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a / b;

  }
};
```

The area I'm having problems with is the while loops I'm trying to make in order to recognize the first instance of one of those operation names occurring in my input string, it looks like this:

```
function doArithment() {
  "use strict"; 
  var i = 0;
  clearResults();
  sepNsLs();
  var found = false;
  var q = 0;
  var keys = Object.keys(operations);
  while (q < keys.length) {
    if (arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys) !== -1) {
      found = true;
      break;
    } else if (arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys) === -1) {
        q += 1;
    } 
  }
  if (found) {
    var result = arrayses.numeros[0];
    while (i < arrayses.numeros.length) {
      if (i === 0) {
        result = arrayses.numeros[0];
      } else {
        result = keys[q](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);
      }
      i += 1;
    }
```

clearResults and sepNsLs should not have any bearing on whether or not this loop works properly, but if it's asked for, I can provide the code for both of those functions. arrayses.letteros is the array of non-numbers from my input string, and that's where I try to look for the operation names, arrayses.numeros is the array in which I put the numbers from my input string. I had a for-in statement working completely in this function, but JSLint doesn't like that, so I've been trying to make this work in other ways. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The program always thinks 
arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys) === -1

even when I have typed an operation name into the input string

Comment: This seems to be the fourth time you've asked a very similar question.  What was lacking in previous answers?

Comment: My program still doesn't work at this point

Comment: I need it to comply with JSLint, and not all of my concerns are addressed when I ask my questions

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the entire keys array. You need to search for the individual element. Anywhere you are referencing `keys` you mean to be referencing `keys[q]`.

`arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys[q])`

Comment: Okay so I've put keys[q] everywhere that searches for it. Now the web console is telling me keys[q] isn't a function on the               result = keys[q](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);      line